# Distinct() values still letting in duplicates

Tags: c#

This is another programming issue in which I think everything looks fine but does not work as intended.

What I'm trying to do is scrape all links from a webpage with htmlagilitypack and add them to a datagrid, but NOT to add duplicates to the datagrid.

**Code:**

```
webBrowser.Navigate(url);

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(webBrowser.DocumentText);

if (debug)
{
    Helpers.SaveDebugToFile(@"Debug\[google.com]-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmssffffff") + "-debug.html", webBrowser.DocumentText);
}

List<string> values = new List<string>();

foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    HtmlAttribute href = link.Attributes["href"];

    if (href.Value.Contains("google.") || href.Value.Contains("search?") || href.Value.StartsWith("/") || href.Value.Length < 5)
    {
        // Ignore.
    }
    else
    {
        // DO NOT ADD TO THE DATAGRID IF href.Value ALREADY EXISTS IN COLUMN 1 //
        values.Add(href.Value);
    }
}

foreach (var value in values.Distinct().ToList())
{
    DataGridViewLinks.Rows.Add(value, randomKeyword);
}
```

The code works but it's still adding duplicates in the first column, but I'm only adding `Distinct()` values in (or that's what I intended it to happen).

I can't see the reason for this issue, i have looked over the code a good few times and don't see anything obvious wrong.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Are the duplicate values spelled exactly the same, casing and all?

Comment: Can you please show some examples of the duplicates that are getting through, that you feel shouldn't.

Comment: Maybe there's a difference that you can't see (space or something like that). And why don't you simply use `if(!values.Any(v=> v == href.Value)) { values.Add(href.Value); }` and simply remove the Distinct in the foreach loop

Comment: It all looks the exact same no differences that i can see, i have added a screenshot of the UI showing duplicates added.

Comment: If you sorted the list you believe has duplicates and edited your question to include it as text it would be much easier to read and possibly figure out.

Comment: Imgur is blocked by loads of corporate firewalls, so all I can see is "enter image description here". Post, as text, the entries in `values` and the resulting output of `values.Distinct().ToList()`, and what your expected output would be.

Comment: Just a thought to debug, why not break the duplicate strings into `char[]` and loop through comparing `char` on `char`. There's bound to be a trailing white space or something odd. Perhaps try a `Trim()` for good measure.

Comment: How many times does the above code block execute? If it executes more than once, that's the source of your problem.  Every time it runs you are appending the "distinct" values from that single execution of the code to your datagrid.  Which doesn't consider what might already be in the data grid.

Comment: Your right mark, it's appending! i execute on every scrape so it is more than once, darn i never even thought, am i best removing duplicates after the scrape is finished or can it be done on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

As it was already mentioned in above comments, most likely somewhere the content isn't exactly equal (different casing, some leading or trailing whitespace, ...)

Better would be to check for duplicates (with defined casing, and removing whitespaces), already when inserting to the "values" list

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Distinct directly in the for loop you can check the result in a List what all values you are getting and then can find whether the problem is in this section of code or any other section. Possibly list is appending while the loop is iterating.